# faster way to do this?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a better way to do something like...

```
int VarableNumberOne = RandomNumberGenerator();
int VarableNumberTwo = RandomNumberGenerator();

if(VarableNumberOne == 4 || VarableNumberOne == 8 || VarableNumberOne == 12)
{
//do code
}
else if(VarableNumberTwo == 4 || VarableNumberTwo == 8 || VarableNumberTwo == 12)
{
//do code
}
```

Person who can come up with the shortest amount of code will win.

Comment: What is wrong with the original code?

Comment: You want "faster", "better" (whatever that means), or "shortest"?

Comment: What can be modified to make this faster? For example: Can you evaluate VarableNumberTwo only in the else-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `RandomNumberGenerator` returns. Assuming that 4, 8 and 12 are the only multiples of 4 that it returns, you could do something like this:

```
if (VarableNumberOne % 4 == 0)
{
    //do code
}
else if (VarableNumberTwo % 4 == 0)
{
    //do code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check inverse mask of required values and if value is not zero.

```
int a = RandomNumberGenerator();
int b = RandomNumberGenerator();

if( a && !( a & ~12 ) )
{
//do code
}
else if( b && !( b & ~12 ) )
{
//do code
}
```

Comment: You have an error in `const int InvMask = ~( 4 & 8 & 12 ); // 0x11110011`, `4 & 8` is 0. It should be `const int InvMask = ~12;`. (and instead of `(v & m) == 0` you could use `!(v & m)` to save a few characters since OP asked for the shortest code).

Comment: **I** wouldn't count whitespace, so yuck for taking that out. But since you're going extreme, use the magic constant directly, `const int m=` needs a lot of `~12` to be compensated ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (variableNumberOne & 12) {
     // ...
} else if (variableNumberTwo & 12) {
    // ...
}
```